# R parallel suddenly not working anymore - error writing to connection

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am using parallel processing of my data in a lot of scripts doing different things. For a while now I get the error message

`Error in serialize(data, node$con, xdr = FALSE) :  error writing to connection`

I tried to find a solution on google, without much success. The code I am using is:

```
  no_cores <- detectCores() - 1    
  cl <- makeCluster(no_cores,type="FORK", outfile='LOG.TXT')
  coords <- as.data.frame(cbind(df$LONG.deg.,df$LAT.deg.))
  dist <-  parApply(cl,coords,1,calc.dist)
  stopCluster(cl)
```

The function used is:

```
  calc.dist <- function(df){
    df <- as.numeric(df)
    message(df[1]," ",df[2])
    dist <- dist2Line(df,baseline)
    return(dist[1])
  }
```

I don't have a reproducible example right now.

I am not using all cores (6 in total). The number of cores I am using doesn't matter, as I get the same error message no matter what.
Changing the size of the data used in the function doesn't make a difference.
My PC has 32 GB of RAM plus 40 GB of swap. I don't think it is a memory problem either.

The logfile after two tries looks like this:

```
starting worker pid=5607 on localhost:11787 at 14:13:12.766
starting worker pid=5608 on localhost:11787 at 14:13:12.784
starting worker pid=5609 on localhost:11787 at 14:13:12.802
starting worker pid=5610 on localhost:11787 at 14:13:12.821
starting worker pid=5611 on localhost:11787 at 14:13:12.839
starting worker pid=5659 on localhost:11787 at 14:15:37.934
starting worker pid=5660 on localhost:11787 at 14:15:37.953
starting worker pid=5661 on localhost:11787 at 14:15:37.971
starting worker pid=5662 on localhost:11787 at 14:15:37.989
starting worker pid=5663 on localhost:11787 at 14:15:38.008
```

No errors in there, RAM not even close to be full. Roughly 10% usage. Cores not busy at all. I have no idea what is causing it. For some parts of the code I simply removed the parallel processing to have it at least working. For others it is important to have parallel processing again.